# Javascript prints value in loop though the print is outside the loop

Tags: javascript

This question was asked before: [Trouble understanding what happens during javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47367918/trouble-understanding-what-happens-during-javascript-for-loop)
but the asker didn't get the right answer and so did I. I learn C++ and Python earlier so I get familiar with loop but when I practing this code:

```
let text = "";
let i;
for(i=0; i<5; i++)
{text += "The number is " + i + " ";}
document.write(text);
```

the output is totally different to what I expected. I visited W3schools but I can't find the answer
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_loop_for_om3

I expected the output is "" because text can't be changed but the code prints out: "The number is 0 The number is 1 The number is 2 The number is 3 The number is 4". My question is why the print executes in the loop though the print is outside the loop? Thank you very much!

Comment: You don't print in the loop. You keep adding more content to the variable called `text` and you print only once, after the loop has finished

Comment: Thanks for answering but why text is not empty string since it was initialized as text = ""?

Comment: the loop will completely execute before your document.write,  so all your concatinations will apply

Comment: I totally forgot that text was reassigned. I was confused with the context string is immutable, can't replace characters in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why the output not empty string because the text variable not empty anymore after for loop. you have assign string when loop so the text variable not empty anymore

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out! I totally forgot that text was reassigned. I was confused with the context string is immutable, can't replace characters in it. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

The print executes as you expect: Only once at the end. In the loop, each time an extra part is appended to `text`. That is:

```js
[iteration 0] ""
[iteration 1] "The number is 0 "
[iteration 2] "The number is 0 The number is 1"
[iteration 3] "The number is 0 The number is 1 The number is 2"
etc.
```

Then in the end, you print the final String which is the concatenation of all the partial Strings you 'glued' together.

Saying `x += y` is the same as saying `x = x + y`. Standard variables (var and let) are still mutable, so if you initialize it as an empty String, you can still append/replace it later.

Try making `text` a `const` instead, and there should be a runtime `TypeError` because you try to reassign a constant.

Comment: How about "Javascript strings are immutable"? I print the text variable, and it should be empty string, why it  prints out the string that was added through the loop?

Comment: I totally forgot that text was reassigned. I was confused with the context string is immutable, can't replace characters in it. Thank you!